# ProductCollection - Custom Field - addFieldToSelect

Tags: magento2

I've created a new field for products. Everything is working perfect.

However, when I call the ProductCollection I always have to add an addFieldToSelect('custom_field') to return the value of the field.

How do I get the new field to ALWAYS return ( without adding the addFieldToSelect() ) when I call the ProductCollection()?

Comment: if you are try this on product listing page then you have to set **Used in Product Listing** to Yes for that custom attribute  from admin attribute edit/detail form

Comment: @Piyush I put the field you mentioned as 'YES', but it still did not show up.

$productCollection = ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->getItemById(10);

The fields that return are just these:
entity_id, attribute_set_id, type_id, sku, has_options, required_options, created_at, updated_at, is_salable

Comment: Did you performed reindexing after those changes?